# Calculating Starting Date Across Multiple Date Ranges

Tags: sql, date, date-range

I have a SQL question which I have not been able to solve for a while now. I have looked everywhere without luck. I spent a lot of time looking through StackOverflow and thought someone here might be able to help.

I need to be able to determine a starting date x number of days back across multiple ranges. For example:

```
Range || Ending Date of Range (date) ||  Number of Days in Range (int)
1     ||  2/20/2013                  ||         44
2     ||  9/5/2014                   ||         75
3     ||  3/25/2016                  ||         20
```

I have 3 ranges lasting various amounts of time with the ending date for each. The date ranges never overlap. I need to count a specific number, let's say 100 days, back in the range. In the example above. The answer would be 2/15/13.

20 + 75 = 95 days. 100 - 95 = 5 days. So 5 days back from 2/20/2013 is 2/15/2013.

Does anyone know how I might go about accomplishing this in a SQL query?

I believe the best way involves adding the ranges together until the sum passes the desired number (100) then taking the difference just prior (95) and subtracting it from (100) which would give me (5) from there its just simple date math. I could easily do this with any programming language but with SQL I am struggling.

Really what I need help with is coming up with (5) and the correct end date (2/20/2013). I can handle the date math from there.

I would appreciate any guidance on how I might a go about accomplishing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please tag it as each can have their own functions (especially when it comes to dates).

Comment: i cannot make sense of this. why you left out range 1? I think you need to explain better the logic here. Why you substract 5 from range 1? makes no sense.

Comment: Tom - DB2...  Ricardo - The Point is to count backwards to get to 100. Date Range 3 + Date Range 2 = 95 What is left over is 5 I can then count back 5 days in that range. Sorry if I am not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in Sybase:

```
SELECT
    max(CASE WHEN total_days >= chosen_days THEN end_date END)
    -
    min(CASE WHEN total_days < chosen_days THEN chosen_days - total_days ELSE chosen_days END)
FROM
    (
        SELECT a.end_date, sum(b.days_in_range) AS total_days, 100 AS chosen_days
        FROM test AS a JOIN test AS b ON a.end_date <= b.end_date
        GROUP BY a.end_date
    ) AS x
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice I will take a look and see what I can make of it. Thanks Again.